# I want a cell(e28) to highlight green when it equals another cell(g6) containing the results of the sum of a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell ( E28 )containing the sum of a column of figures of bank payments that I want to highlight green, when it equals another cell (G6 ) containing the sum of another column of figures of items ordered, I have tries conditional formatting 'cell value, equal to, $G$6 but no joy, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure both values are exactly equal? Try rounding the values

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what exactly it is you're building? Your description is a bit sparse, so it would help a lot being able to see what you're describing.

Comment: Both cells are the results of two different columns sum function E28 is the sum a column of 'bank withdrawals', and G6 is the sum of a column of 'goods ordered' I just want indication that what has left the bank is the same amount as the goods ordered

Comment: From your description, we can't find the problem, using "$G$6" in a formula with conditional formatting works on my environment, the screenshot is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MicDZ.jpg).